# Sample Oracle DB for Real Estate Agency

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, check-constraints

Im trying to build a sample database for a project about a real estate agency,on the table about the realties i have a column Realtie_id and i want it to start with 11%%% what type should it be (int or varchar ) and how do I make the constraint ?

```
 create table Realties (
    rid int not null,
    address varchar(50),
    m2 real not null,
    r_type varchar(20),
    primary key (rid),
    constraint c_rid check(rid in (.....
    );
```

Comment: As others have said, if it is a character string, make it a varchar2.  If it is a _truely_ a number, make it NUMBER.  I would caution that if it, by convention, uses only numeric characters, that does not necessarily make it a NUMBER.  Only if it ever makes sense to use it in a math operation is it a number.  Think about telephone 'numbers', Americian social security 'numbers', credit card 'numbers'.  They are all numeric characters, but the convention, when they were designed, could just as easily been alpha. You'd never add them. They are not NUMBERs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you'll be storing in there.

- if it is a string, use `VARCHAR2`
- if it is a number, use `NUMBER` (or `INT`)

Constraint in any case might be

```
SQL> create table realties
  2    (rid int constraint ch_rid check (substr(to_char(rid), 1, 2) = '11'));

Table created.

SQL> insert into realties (rid) values ('abc');
insert into realties (rid) values ('abc')
                                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number


SQL> insert into realties (rid) values ('245');
insert into realties (rid) values ('245')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CH_RID) violated


SQL> insert into realties (rid) values ('1245');
insert into realties (rid) values ('1245')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CH_RID) violated


SQL> insert into realties (rid) values ('11245');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your value is a number then make the column a numeric data type. The exception to this is when your value is a number string that can start with zeroes, like a phone number, when it should be a string data type; otherwise if you use a number data type then the, semantically important, leading zeroes will be stripped off. Since you want the number to start with `11` then this caveat does not apply.

As for the `CHECK` constraint, you can use `LIKE '11%'` and Oracle will implicitly convert it to a string to perform the check.

```sql
create table Realties (
  rid     int
          not null
          CONSTRAINT realties__rid__pk PRIMARY KEY
          CONSTRAINT realties__rid__chk CHECK ( rid LIKE '11%' ),
  address varchar(50),
  m2      real
          not null,
  r_type  varchar(20)
);
```